# Boto3: Get aws_security_token

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am able to get access_key and secret_key but I am not able to get security token.
This works:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials() 
print credentials.access_key
print credentials.secret_key
```

This doesn't:
`print credentials.session_token`

neither this:
`print credentials.security_token`

nor this:

```
client = boto3.client('sts')
client.get_session_token()
```

gives me this error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: Cannot call GetSessionToken with session credentials
```

Please help!

Comment: Why do you wish to obtain the token? Are you running this on an EC2 instance with a role, or a local machine with a credentials file?

Comment: I am running it on local machine. I need to use this token in some other part of the code.

Comment: Why do you think you should be getting a security token? They are only provided when credentials have been created via the Security Token Service (such as when a Role is assigned to an EC2 instance). The credentials you are using probably don't have a security token assigned.

Comment: The credentials do have security token assigned to them, they are present in the credentials file im .\aws\credentials

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials() 
print credentials.token
```

I discovered that via `print credentials.__dict__`